# Lyx error: Could not find bind file: ertWarning

Tags: errors, lyx, document-configuration

I use Lyx 2.0.2 under Linux and I've never hat problems. Since yesterday Lyx does not recognize short cuts. Every time when I try to configure Lyx using the Lyx gui (tools - new configuration) I get the following message:

> Fehler beim Lesen der Konfigurationsdatei
>   ert.
>   Bitte prüfen Sie Ihre Installation.

I've already deinstalled and installed Lyx  but the problem is still there. 
If I call Lxy on the console with the dbg-Option 4 (key), I obtain the following output:

> lyx -dbg 4
>   Festlegen des Test-Levels auf 4
>   Testen von `key' (Verarbeitung von Tastatureingaben)
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777236, Right
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777234, Left
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777235, Up
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777237, Down
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777217, Tab
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777217, Tab
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777217,   ISO_Left_Tab
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777218,   BackTab
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777232, Home
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777233, End
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777238, Prior
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777239, Next
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777220,   Return
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777223,   Delete
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777219,   BackSpace
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777221, KP_Enter
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777236, KP_Right
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777234, KP_Left
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777235, KP_Up
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777237, KP_Down
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777232,   KP_Home
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777233, KP_End
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777238, KP_Prior
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 16777239, KP_Next
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>
> ### Could not find bind file: ertWarning: Es konnte keine Tastenkürzeldatei   gefunden werden.
>
> Fehler beim Lesen der Konfigurationsdatei
>   ert.
>   Bitte prüfen Sie Ihre Installation.
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 76, l
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(635): Init key to 76, l
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1
>   ../../../../src/frontends/qt4/GuiKeySymbol.cpp(642): isOK is 1

What do I have  to do exactly in order to check the installation and to solve the problem?

Comment: Exit LyX, rename `~/.lyx` to something else, and restart LyX. `~/.lyx` contains your preferences, shortcuts, templates (if any), and other things. Look in the folder "bind" to see the shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Exit LyX, rename `~/.lyx` to something else, and restart LyX. `~/.lyx` contains your preferences, shortcuts, templates (if any), and other things. Look in the folder "bind" to see the shortcuts.