# Lyx error - Changing the control keys

Tags: lyx

I wished to re-define the control keys for directly change Alt+A 1 (selection chapter) towards Alt+1. So the control-key-file was not chosen. I've search for the correct control key, deleted it and gave the new control key for Alt+1. After saving the settings the program came up with the problem
"Fehler beim Lesen der Konfigurationsdatei ert. Bitte prüfen Sie Ihre Installation."

[Lyx error: Could not find bind file: ertWarning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171618/lyx-error-could-not-find-bind-file-ertwarning)
I tried to solve my problem by renaming the document after closing the software but it was not successful.

So I came up with the idea that the file is actually not loaded. By chosing one of the files
I was able to close the error notification when I want to open the general settings of Lyx.

[image]

Now I want to redefine 
Alt+1 for chapter
Alt+2 for section
Alt+3 ...

How can I find this keys
Do I have to chose one file e.g. cyrkeys.bind or some other file?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change any file directly. Just go to Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts

Then search for the shortcut and click on "Modify". Then "Delete Key", then click on the empty box and do a "Alt 3".

If you do that and you get an error, this sounds like a bug in LyX. Can you please send an email to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org? There are some German users that might be able to reproduce the bug. I cannot. I'm thinking it might depend on the keyboard layout.

Comment: I like to use the shortcut to change towards standard with "layout standard" and shortcut "Alt+A S". How can I do this? I found no information in the LyX manual. If I select a word press Alt, hold it, press A, hold it and press S nothing happens. If I select a word press Alt, hold it, press A, release A for a short time and press S nothing happens too. Is there a way to access this shortcut "Alt+A S"?

Comment: @laminin I'm not sure what's going on. For me it works fine if I follow the procedure I described above. Instead of "Alt 3" I press "Alt A" then I release then I press "S". Then the shortcut is set. Maybe a difference in operating systems? I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: If I press "Alt A" then I release and then press "S" nothing happens. I guess the operating system is the reason, because I'm using Windows.

Comment: @laminin I see, so the Alt A shows up, and then when you press another button it does not change anything in the box that has "Alt A"? This is a bug. It might be a bug in Qt so I'm not sure there's something we can do about it, but please file a report at http://www.lyx.org/trac